# Function/macro to execute function body only when arguments changed from last call

Tags: macros, clojure, functional-programming, clojurescript

This should work similar to `memoize`, but very differently. While memoize should be used with pure functions, it is often useful to speed up IO related functions.

The function/macro I'm looking for should behave like higher order function. The function it produces should:

- when called for 1st time, it should call the original function, passing arguments to it
- remember: arguments, return value
- when called 2nd time

  - with the same arguments: it should return memoized return value
  - with different arguments: forget last arguments and return value, call the original function, remember current arguments and return value
- when called nth time, always compare the arguments to the last call, and behave like described above.

Comment: This is exactly like memoize except it only remembers one argument->value pair.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be easy enough to modify the source of `memoize` to do this.

```
(defn memo-one [f]
  (let [mem (atom {})]
    (fn [& args]
      (if-let [e (find @mem args)]
        (val e)
        (let [ret (apply f args)]
          (reset! mem {args ret})
          ret)))))

(defn foo [x] (println "called foo") x)
(def memo-foo (memo-one foo))
```

However, there is already a flexible memoization library available that can do this.

```
(require '[clojure.core.memoize :as memo])

(defn foo [x] (println "called foo") x)
(def memo-foo (memo/lru foo :lru/threshold 1))
```

---

```
(memo-foo 1)
; called foo
; 1
(memo-foo 1)
; 1
(memo-foo 2)
; called foo
; 2  
(memo-foo 1)
; called foo
; 1
```

Comment: nice, in particular that you avoid swapping in the case where the value is already held

Comment: I realized I needed something completely different (custom caching strategy), but basically I ended up using this before the realization. Bonus question: fast, memory efficient way to compare typed arrays :) (yup, those are my arguments, and I reuse them for performance).

Comment: @skrat I suggest asking your bonus question as a new question with details about how you are using the arrays. If you are _reusing_ identical arrays, then the answer is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using clojure.core only. I borrowed the `foo` function from A. Webb's example for demonstration.

```
(defn memoize-1
  [f]
  (let [previous (atom nil)]
    (fn [& args]
      (second
       (swap! previous
              (fn [[prev-args prev-val :as prev]]
                (if (and prev (= prev-args args))
                  prev
                  [args (apply f args)])))))))


user> (defn foo [x] (println "called foo") x)
#'user/foo
user> (def memo-foo (memoize-1 foo))
#'user/memo-foo
user> (memo-foo 1)
called foo
1
user> (memo-foo 1)
1
user> (memo-foo 2)
called foo
2
user> (memo-foo 1)
called foo
1
```